# How to fix the zookeeper timeout issue in spark streaming job

Tags: python, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to do some analysis on twitter streaming data. The tweets are consumed successfully through kafkaconsumer. Now I am trying to stream those tweets through spark streaming job to do some aggregation. But the code is error'd out with zookeeper timeout issue.

I increased the time out limit in kafka server.properties file and restarted the zookeeper and kafka but the increased timeout values set in server.properties file is not reflecting when running the code and failing with same error.

**Changes made to server.properties file**

```
zookeeper.connect=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=45000
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=50000
```

**My code:**

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.0 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark import SparkContext
#    Spark Streaming
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
#    Kafka
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
#    json parsing
import json

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSparkStreamingKafka_RM_01")
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)

kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:6667','spark-streaming', {'twitter-topic':1})

parsed = kafkaStream.map(lambda v: v)

parsed.count().map(lambda x:'Tweets in this batch: %s' % x).pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

**Error**

```
2019-01-06 02:19:12 ERROR ReceiverTracker:91 - Receiver has been stopped. Try to restart it.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
```

I have looked for this issue at many forums but didnt find any solution. Looking forward to some help on this. Thanks in advance.

I am using HDP 2.6 and my kafka broker settings at /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/config are

```
auto.create.topics.enable=true
auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true
broker.rack=/default-rack
compression.type=producer
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3
controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=5000
controller.message.queue.size=10
controller.socket.timeout.ms=30000
default.replication.factor=1
delete.topic.enable=false
external.kafka.metrics.exclude.prefix=kafka.network.RequestMetrics,kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory,kafka.server.BrokerTopicMetrics.BytesRejectedPerSec
external.kafka.metrics.include.prefix=kafka.network.RequestMetrics.ResponseQueueTimeMs.request.OffsetCommit.98percentile,kafka.network.RequestMetrics.ResponseQueueTimeMs.request.Offsets.95percentile,kafka.network.RequestMetrics.ResponseSendTimeMs.request.Fetch.95percentile,kafka.network.RequestMetrics.RequestsPerSec.request
fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=10000
kafka.ganglia.metrics.group=kafka
kafka.ganglia.metrics.host=localhost
kafka.ganglia.metrics.port=8671
kafka.ganglia.metrics.reporter.enabled=false
kafka.metrics.reporters=
kafka.timeline.metrics.host=
kafka.timeline.metrics.hosts=
kafka.timeline.metrics.maxRowCacheSize=10000
kafka.timeline.metrics.port=
kafka.timeline.metrics.protocol=
kafka.timeline.metrics.reporter.enabled=false
kafka.timeline.metrics.reporter.sendInterval=5900
kafka.timeline.metrics.truststore.password=
kafka.timeline.metrics.truststore.path=
kafka.timeline.metrics.truststore.type=
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10
listeners=PLAINTEXT://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:6667
log.cleanup.interval.mins=10
log.dirs=/kafka-logs
log.index.interval.bytes=4096
log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760
log.retention.bytes=-1
log.retention.hours=168
log.roll.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
message.max.bytes=1000000
min.insync.replicas=1
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=3
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
num.replica.fetchers=1
offset.metadata.max.bytes=4096
offsets.commit.required.acks=-1
offsets.commit.timeout.ms=5000
offsets.load.buffer.size=5242880
offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000
offsets.retention.minutes=86400000
offsets.topic.compression.codec=0
offsets.topic.num.partitions=50
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
offsets.topic.segment.bytes=104857600
port=6667
producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=10000
queued.max.requests=500
replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576
replica.fetch.min.bytes=1
replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=500
replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms=5000
replica.lag.max.messages=4000
replica.lag.time.max.ms=10000
replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536
replica.socket.timeout.ms=30000
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=GSSAPI
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=GSSAPI
security.inter.broker.protocol=PLAINTEXT
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
zookeeper.connect=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=45000
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=50000
zookeeper.sync.time.ms=2000
```

Comment: Kafka should work with Zookeeper already, not sure why you needed to change it. But if you did, do it through Ambari, not directly on the file. Note: HDP 2.6 Sandbox is using a fairly old version of Kafka and Spark. You might get better ingregrations with Streaming technologies using HDF Sandbox

Comment: @cricket_007    But HDF doesnt have services to perform historical data analysis.. though it provides capability to install hdf on hdp, it is all a complicated process.. Is there a way to do both streaming and historical analysis without complex setup.. My agenda here is to learn the use of the services but it is taking more time for me to work on configuration to make these services work? Would you suggest any other distribution instead of hortonworks?